# Removing NA values from rows, without removing the rows in R

Tags: r, row, na

I have a dataset in which the data would look something like this:
[a fragment dataframe with the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy2Ae.png)
So lot's of NA's per row, but also regular answers, that I want in the final version.
Is it possible to remove the NAs, but without removing the rows as a whole?
I thought about pivoting and removing rows with NA, but then it would just remove the occurences that have actual answers as well.
The data is coming form a decision making procedure in qualtrics, in which not every option is displayed to the participants (hence the NAs), but we do not want to exclude people in any step. I also thought about maybe recoding the values, and subsetting them somehow, but that doesn't seem to work out right in my mind when it comes to the actual analysis.

I tried removing the NAs, as well as pivoting the table and removing them later.
I do not yet have the full dataset, but want to experiment on strategies of data analysis before I have the data collected, to not get lost once I have it.

Comment: May you clarify what you intend with "removing the NAs"? What should go in NA's place? If the data is "not available", then NA looks perfectly appropriate. Perhaps some more details about what you want to achieve may be helpful?

Comment: So you want an empty space in place of the NA values? You can certainly arrange to _print_ your data frames that way, but in R NA values mean 'there is a missing value here - acknowledge that it is missing and leave space for it in the data structure'. If you want the NA cells to appear blank, then you can't 'get rid' of the NA values. You would have to replace them with an empty string. Of course, this can't be done with numeric values without converting to character. You should get used to the fact that there is no such thing as an 'empty' cell in a data frame. It either has a value or is NA